# Issue creating a generic Data Wrapper

Tags: c#, .net, generics, .net-4.0, data-access-layer

I am having an issue creating my (mostly) generic data access wrapper

## Code

```
/// <summary>
/// Get the results of a stronly-typed IList Object
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T">Strongly-Typed class of objects that should be returned</typeparam>
/// <param name="_DBType">The type of database to use</param>
/// <param name="_Qry">The query to run</param>
/// <param name="_QryType">The Query Type to run</param>
/// <param name="_ParamNames">The Parameters' names to pass to the query, if any</param>
/// <param name="_ParamVals">The Parameters' values to pass to the query, if any</param>
/// <param name="_ParamDTs">The Parameters' data types to pass to the query, if any</param>
/// <param name="_ShouldCache">Should we cache the response</param>
/// <param name="_CacheID">Cache item name</param>
/// <returns>Strongly Typed ilist of objects</returns>
public static IList<T> GetResults<T>(Enumerators.DatabaseTypes _DBType, 
                                    string _Qry, 
                                    CommandType _QryType,
                                    string[] _ParamNames = null,
                                    object[] _ParamVals = null,
                                    Enumerators.DataTypes[] _ParamDTs = null,
                                    bool _ShouldCache = false,
                                    string _CacheID = "") where T : new()
{
    // Create a reference to a potential already cached IList
    IList<T> _CachedItem = _Cache.Get<IList<T>>(_CacheID);
    // If we're already cached, there's no need to fire up the data access objects, so return the cached item instead
    if (_CachedItem != null && _ShouldCache)
    {
        return _CachedItem;
    }
    else
    {
        // Fire up our data access object
        switch (_DBType)
        { 
            case Enumerators.DatabaseTypes.SqlServer:
                SqlServer.Access db = new SqlServer.Access();
                break;
            case Enumerators.DatabaseTypes.SqlCE:
                SqlCE.Access db = new SqlCE.Access();
                break;
            case Enumerators.DatabaseTypes.MySql:
                MySql.Access db = new MySql.Access();
                break;
            case Enumerators.DatabaseTypes.OLE:
                Ole.Access db = new Ole.Access();
                break;
            case Enumerators.DatabaseTypes.ODBC:
                Odbc.Access db = new Odbc.Access();
                break;
            default:
                db = null;
        }
        using (db)
        {
            try
            {
                // create a new ilist reference of our strongly typed class
                IList<T> _Query = default(IList<T>);
                // set the query type
                db.QueryType = _QryType;
                // set the query text
                db.Query = _Qry;
                // make sure we've got some parameters, if we do the set them to our db access object
                if (_ParamNames != null)
                {
                    // set the parameter names
                    db.ParameterNames = _ParamNames;
                    // set the parameter values
                    db.ParameterValues = _ParamVals;
                    // set the parameter data types
                    db.ParameterDataTypes = _ParamDTs;
                }
                // start using our db access :)  Fire off the GetResults method and return back a SqlDataReader to work on
                using (DbDataReader r = db.GetResults())
                {
                    // make sure the data reader actually exists and contains some results
                    if (r != null)
                    {
                        // map the data reader to our strongly type(s)
                        _Query = Map<T>(r);
                    }
                    r.Close();
                }
                // check if we should cache the results
                if (_ShouldCache)
                {
                    // if so, set the query object to the cache
                    _Cache.Set<IList<T>>(_Query, _CacheID);
                }
                // return our strongly typed list
                return _Query;
            }
            catch (DbException dEx)
            {
                // Catch an exception if any, an write it out to our logging mechanism, in addition to adding it our returnable message property
                _Msg += "Wrapper.GetResults Exception: " + dEx.Message + db.Message;
                ErrorReporting.WriteEm.WriteItem(dEx, "o7th.Class.Library.Data.Wrapper.GetResults", _Msg);
                // make sure this method returns a default List
                return default(IList<T>);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // Catch an exception if any, an write it out to our logging mechanism, in addition to adding it our returnable message property
                _Msg += "Wrapper.GetResults Exception: " + ex.Message + db.Message;
                ErrorReporting.WriteEm.WriteItem(ex, "o7th.Class.Library.Data.Wrapper.GetResults", _Msg);
                // make sure this method returns a default List
                return default(IList<T>);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

## Access Class - SqlServer

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace o7th.Class.Library.Data.SqlServer
{
internal class Access : IDisposable
{

#region "Properties"

    // Set the type of query we are running
    private CommandType _QT;
    internal CommandType QueryType { set { _QT = value; } }

    // Set the actual query text to run
    private string _Qry;
    internal string Query { set { _Qry = value; } }

    // Set the parameter names if there are any
    private string[] _PNs;
    internal string[] ParameterNames { set { _PNs = value; } }

    // Set the parameter values if there are any
    private object[] _PVs;
    internal object[] ParameterValues { set { _PVs = value; } }

    // Set the actual Sql Data Types if there are any
    private DataTypes[] _DTs;
    internal DataTypes[] ParameterDataTypes { set { _DTs = value; } }

    // Check to see if there are any parameters passed
    private bool AreParams() {
        // Check to see if the values and names are null first
        if (_PVs != null && _PNs != null) {
            try {
                Type _t_pv = _PVs.GetType();
                Type _t_pn = _PNs.GetType();
                if (_t_pv.IsArray && _t_pn.IsArray) {
                    return (_PVs.Length > 0 && _PNs.Length > 0) ? true : false;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            } catch {
                // yes I meant to do this, we really don't need to get the exception here
                return false;
            }
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    // Get a return message if any
    private string _Msg;
    internal string Message { get { return _Msg; } }

    // Set the official Sql Reader object
    private SqlDataReader _Rdr;
    // Set the official Sql Connection object
    private SqlConnection _Conn;
    // Set the official Sql Command object
    private SqlCommand _Cmd;
    // Hack for seeing if we're disposed already
    private bool disposedValue;

#endregion

    // Constructor
    internal Access() {
        Invoke();
    }

    // Official Constructor.  We can thread these 2 becuase they are not being used yet, and it makes it slightly more efficient
    internal void Invoke() {
        try { 
            Parallel.Invoke(() => {
                _Conn = new SqlConnection(AssemblyProperties.GetConnectionString());
            }, () =>
            {
                _Cmd = new SqlCommand();
            });
        }
        catch (SqlException dEx)
        {
            // Catch an exception if any, an write it out to our logging mechanism, in addition to adding it our returnable message property
            _Msg = "Access.Invoke Exception: " + dEx.Message;
            ErrorReporting.WriteEm.WriteItem(dEx, "o7th.Class.Library.Data.SqlServer.Access.Invoke", _Msg);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _Msg = "Access.Invoke Exception: " + ex.Message;
            ErrorReporting.WriteEm.WriteItem(ex, "o7th.Class.Library.Data.SqlServer.Access.Invoke", _Msg);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Return a SqlDataReader based on the properties passed to this class
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    internal SqlDataReader GetResults()
    {
        try {
            // check for parameters
            if (AreParams()) {
                PrepareParams(_Cmd);
            }
            // set our connection
            _Cmd.Connection = _Conn;
            // set the type of query to run
            _Cmd.CommandType = _QT;
            // set the actual query to run
            _Cmd.CommandText = _Qry;
            // open the connection
            _Cmd.Connection.Open();
            // prepare the command with any parameters that may have gotten added
            _Cmd.Prepare();
            // Execute the SqlDataReader, and set the connection to close once returned
            _Rdr = _Cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
            // clear out any parameters
            _Cmd.Parameters.Clear();
            // return our reader object
            return (!_Rdr.HasRows) ? null : _Rdr;
        }
        catch (SqlException SqlEx)
        {
            _Msg += "Acccess.GetResults SqlException: " + SqlEx.Message;
            ErrorReporting.WriteEm.WriteItem(SqlEx, "o7th.Class.Library.Data.SqlServer.Access.GetResults", _Msg);
            return null;
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            _Msg += "Acccess.GetResults Exception: " + ex.Message;
            ErrorReporting.WriteEm.WriteItem(ex, "o7th.Class.Library.Data.SqlServer.Access.GetResults", _Msg);
            return null;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Execute a non-return query, and return the success
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    internal bool Execute() {
        try {
            // check for parameters
            if (AreParams()) {
                PrepareParams(_Cmd);
            }
            // set our connection
            _Cmd.Connection = _Conn;
            // set the type of query to run
            _Cmd.CommandType = _QT;
            // set the actual query to run
            _Cmd.CommandText = _Qry;
            // open the connection
            _Cmd.Connection.Open();
            // prepare the command with any parameters that may have gotten added
            _Cmd.Prepare();
            // execute the non-returnable query against the database
            _Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            // clear out any parameters
            _Cmd.Parameters.Clear();
            // executed successfully (otherwise would have thrown an exception)
            return true;
        }
        catch (SqlException SqlEx)
        {
            _Msg += "Access.Execute SqlException: " + SqlEx.Message;
            ErrorReporting.WriteEm.WriteItem(SqlEx, "o7th.Class.Library.Data.SqlServer.Access.Execute", _Msg);
            return false;
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            _Msg += "Access.Execute Exception: " + ex.Message;
            ErrorReporting.WriteEm.WriteItem(ex, "o7th.Class.Library.Data.SqlServer.Access.Execute", _Msg);
            return false;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Execute a query with a return value.  Used in Selecting the ID of the last inserted record.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
    /// <param name="_DefVal"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    internal T ExecuteWithReturn<T>(T _DefVal) {
        try {
            T _Ret;
            // check for parameters
            if (AreParams()) {
                PrepareParams(_Cmd);
            }
            // set our connection
            _Cmd.Connection = _Conn;
            // set the type of query to run
            _Cmd.CommandType = _QT;
            // set the actual query to run
            _Cmd.CommandText = _Qry;
            // open the connection
            _Cmd.Connection.Open();
            // prepare the command with any parameters that may have gotten added
            _Cmd.Prepare();
            T _T = (T)_Cmd.ExecuteScalar();
            _Ret = (_T is DBNull) ? default(T) : _T;
            // clear out _T
            _T = default(T);
            // clear out any parameters
            _Cmd.Parameters.Clear();
            // return the single return value from the query run
            return _Ret;
        }
        catch (SqlException SqlEx)
        {
            _Msg += "Access.ExecuteWithReturn SqlException: " + SqlEx.Message;
            ErrorReporting.WriteEm.WriteItem(SqlEx, "o7th.Class.Library.Data.SqlServer.Access.ExecuteWithReturn", _Msg);
            return default(T);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            _Msg += "Access.ExecuteWithReturn Exception: " + ex.Message;
            ErrorReporting.WriteEm.WriteItem(ex, "o7th.Class.Library.Data.SqlServer.Access.ExecuteWithReturn", _Msg);
            return default(T);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Prepare our parameters, adding them and forcing a valid data length
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="objCmd"></param>
    protected void PrepareParams(SqlCommand objCmd) {
        try  {
            // set our initial Data Size
            int _DataSize = 0;
            // get the number of Parameter Values passed in
            int _PCt = _PVs.GetUpperBound(0);
            // begin array check
            Type _t_dt = _DTs.GetType();
            // start looping over our parameters
            for (int i = 0; i <= _PCt; ++i) {
                // make sure that the data types are actually an array
                if (_t_dt.IsArray) {
                    // select which datatype, and force the official size
                    switch ((int)_DTs[i]) {
                        case 0:
                        case 33:
                        case 6:
                        case 9:
                        case 13:
                        case 19:
                            _DataSize = 8;
                            break;
                        case 1:
                        case 3:
                        case 7:
                        case 10:
                        case 12:
                        case 21:
                        case 22:
                        case 23:
                        case 25:
                            _DataSize = _PVs[i].ToString().Length;
                            break;
                        case 2:
                        case 20:
                            _DataSize = 1;
                            break;
                        case 5:
                            _DataSize = 17;
                            break;
                        case 8:
                        case 17:
                        case 15:
                            _DataSize = 4;
                            break;
                        case 14:
                            _DataSize = 16;
                            break;
                        case 31:
                            _DataSize = 3;
                            break;
                        case 32:
                            _DataSize = 5;
                            break;
                        case 16:
                            _DataSize = 2;
                            break;
                    }
                    // add our parameter to the command object
                    objCmd.Parameters.Add(_PNs[i], (SqlDbType)_DTs[i], _DataSize).Value = _PVs[i]; 
                } else {
                    // if the datatypes were not set, try to add them generically
                    objCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(_PNs[i], _PVs[i]);
                }
            }
            // clean up
            _PNs = null;_PVs = null;_DTs = null;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            _Msg += "Access.PrepareParams Exception: " + ex.Message;
            ErrorReporting.WriteEm.WriteItem(ex, "o7th.Class.Library.Data.SqlServer.Access.PrepareParams", _Msg);
        }
    }

#region "Dispose Support"

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (!disposedValue && disposing) {
            try
            {
                _Qry = string.Empty;
                _Rdr.Close();
                _Rdr.Dispose();
                _Cmd.Connection.Close();
                _Cmd.Dispose();
                if (_Conn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                {
                    SqlConnection.ClearAllPools();
                    _Conn.Close();
                    _Conn.Dispose();
                }
                _Msg = null;
            }
            catch(Exception ex) {
                ErrorReporting.WriteEm.WriteItem(ex, "o7th.Class.Library.Data.SqlServer.Access.Dispose", "");
            }
        }
        disposedValue = true;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

#endregion

}
}
```

The issue I am having is, because I need the `switch` statement to select which database `Access` method should be used, it is throwing `The name 'db' does not exist in the current context` errors all over the place.

I've also attempted to `var db;` prior to the `switch` statement with the `Implicitly-typed local variables` error.

I will not know which type of database will be used until it is time to actually use this, so how can I make sure this works?

```
        IDbAccess db;
        switch (_DBType)
        { 
            case Enumerators.DatabaseTypes.SqlServer:
                SqlServer.Access db = new SqlServer.Access();
                break;
            case Enumerators.DatabaseTypes.SqlCE:
                SqlCE.Access db = new SqlCE.Access();
                break;
            case Enumerators.DatabaseTypes.MySql:
                MySql.Access db = new MySql.Access();
                break;
            case Enumerators.DatabaseTypes.OLE:
                Ole.Access db = new Ole.Access();
                break;
            case Enumerators.DatabaseTypes.ODBC:
                Odbc.Access db = new Odbc.Access();
                break;
            default:
                db = null;
        }
```

is producing `Cannot implicitly convert type 'SqlCE.Access to SqlServer.Access'` errors down the line, as well as `A local variable 'db' is already defined in this scope` and `A local variable named 'db' cannot be declared in this scope because it would give a different meaning to 'db' which is already used in a parent of current scope to denote something else`

Comment: What class/interface SqlServer.Access, SqlCE.Access, MySql.Access, Ole.Access, and Odbc.Access inherit/implement?

Comment: Nothing other than IDisposable.  Each database type's `Access` class does something different for each one

Comment: I'll post one of the Access classes in the question

Comment: @o7thWebDesign Then you should really edit them so that they *do* implement an interface with all of the functionality that you use in this method, since they're your types and you can edit them.

Comment: You need to define an interface (IDbAccess, for example) that contains methods/properties that are common between them, then have those classes implement the interface.  Once that's in place you can define `db` as `IDbAccess db` and all the other things should fall in place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of those various database providers should have some sort of base class they all inherit from or an interface that they all implement.  That base class/interface should have all of the operations that you use later on in the method.  Create a variable of that base type/interface before the `switch` and then assign that variable a value in each `case`.

Comment: #1, not really sure what you are talking about here... (I'm a c# noob); #2 Would this apply to the MySql .Net Connector even?

Comment: @o7thWebDesign These are pretty basic concepts, so I'd suggest you do some research into the terms that you are unfamiliar with before continuing; it's beyond the scope of an SO question to explain those concepts.